# False Ceiling Lighting Effect using three.js

Tags: three.js

Hi I am trying to make false ceiling in three.js ,
Any suggestions how can I achieve rope lighting effect via three.js??

Comment: can you clarify those concepts: "false ceiling", "rope lighting effect"? Also pictures may help.

Comment: I want to make something like this : http://gayatricreations.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/false-ceiling-design-in-kolkata.jpg

Comment: Any piece of code to get started with? If you are looking for inspiration in the http://threejs.org/examples you can find something to get started with.